# Modal Close Function not working when im click the close button

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick, modal-dialog

```
    const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const openModal= ()=>{
        setModalOpen(true);
        
    }
    const closeModal = () => {
        setModalOpen(false);
      };

   
  return (
    <div className='bg-slate-300 dark:bg-slate-800 rounded-lg overflow-hidden' onClick={openModal}>
        </div>

        {modalOpen && (
                <div className='fixed inset-0 bg-slate-300 dark:bg-slate-900 bg-opacity-50 backdrop-blur flex justify-center items-center lg:w-6/12 sm:w-10/12 m-auto max-h-max rounded-md' visible>
                    <div className='dark:bg-slate-700 p-2 rounded'>
                        <span className='absolute top-0 right-0 m-2 text-red-600 text-lg cursor-pointer' onClick={closeModal}>
                            &times;
                        </span>
 
                        <button onClick={closeModal} className="mt-2 bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 px-3 py-1 rounded">
                            Close Modal
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}

    </div>
  )
}
```

here i'm used react and tailwind css. its open this modal, but when i **click close button or x , its not closing**. what am i do now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your entire component (including button and modal) inside of a React Fragment.

Make sure to open the div for the modal.
Here's the fixed code.

```
      const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
      const openModal= ()=>{
          setModalOpen(true);
          
      }
      const closeModal = () => {
          setModalOpen(false);
        };

     
    return (
      <>
       <div className='bg-slate-300 dark:bg-slate-800 rounded-lg overflow-hidden' onClick={openModal}>
    Open
      </div>
      <div>
      {modalOpen && (
              <div className='fixed inset-0 bg-slate-300 dark:bg-slate-900 bg-opacity-50 backdrop-blur flex justify-center items-center lg:w-6/12 sm:w-10/12 m-auto max-h-max rounded-md' visible>
                  <div className='dark:bg-slate-700 p-2 rounded'>

                      <button onClick={closeModal} className="mt-2 bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 px-3 py-1 rounded">
                      <span className='absolute top-0 right-0 m-2 text-red-600 text-lg cursor-pointer' onClick={closeModal}>
                          &times;
                      </span>
                      </button>
                          Close Modal
                  </div>
              </div>
          )}

  </div>
      </>
    )
```

Comment: I guess i solved it!

Comment: This is a simple you know.